# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly "locking up" - USB issues?

Tags: boot, usb, 20.04

This is on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my desktop. I started out with Ubuntu Server 20.04, then added GNOME to it for a minimal setup. This is on a self built system with a Ryzen 7 1800x and a Gigabyte AX370 Gaming 5 motherboard. The OS is booting off a NVMe drive in UEFI mode.

The problem is that sometimes, out of the blue, my machine would lock up. This happened back in 18.04 as well, but not that often (like once every week or so, but now I've seen 4 crashes in the past hour already). The other difference is when my system locks up in 18.04, I'd still be able to ping or SSH into it, but in 20.04, the system would drop off the network altogether. No replies to pings at all.

I checked `dmesg` to see what could've gone wrong, but I didn't find anything in there that indicates any type of problem. So I looked at syslog messages, narrowing down to the moments before the system crashed, and noticed:

```
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37963]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu kernel: [43202.523116] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0C04.2991: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Memory, Inc. Integrated USB Bridge] on usb-0000:02:00.0-12/input0
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu kernel: [43202.532084] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0C04.2992: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Memory, Inc. Integrated USB Bridge] on usb-0000:02:00.0-12/input0
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37965]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu kernel: [43202.541495] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0C04.2993: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Memory, Inc. Integrated USB Bridge] on usb-0000:02:00.0-12/input0
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37967]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37969]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37971]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu fido_id[37973]: 1-12:1.0: Failed to open report descriptor at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.0/usb1/1-12/1-12:1.0/report_descriptor': No such file or directory
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu kernel: [43202.601501] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:1C07.2994: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [                                                ] on usb-0000:02:00.0-13.2/input0
May  3 16:33:39 ubuntu kernel: [43202.606771] hid-generic 0003:1B1C:0C04.2995: hiddev4,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Device [Corsair Memory, Inc. Integrated USB Bridge] on usb-0000:02:00.0-12/input0

<... a bunch of invalid characters here...>

Invalid argument
May  3 16:36:06 ubuntu systemd-modules-load[625]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

From this, I believe that `Invalid argument` is the last line before the system stopped responding... but that doesn't seem to say much (if at all) about the problem.

`ls -al /var/crash` is showing that the crash directory is pretty empty:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root 4096 May  3 19:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 May  3 03:02 ..
```

Also, here's more output from `free -h`, `sysctl vm.swappiness`, and `dmidecode -s bios-version`:

```
root@ubuntu:~# free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           47Gi       1.4Gi        45Gi       3.0Mi       637Mi        45Gi
Swap:          15Gi          0B        15Gi
root@ubuntu:~# sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
root@ubuntu:~# dmidecode -s bios-version
F50a
```

Memory configuration:

```
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 9
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 48GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2400C15/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: AF2C5F46
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX2400C15/8G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 2
          serial: BE2A03A9
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK32GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
```

The other big thing running on the system is a KVM guest, running Windows 10, with a passed-through GPU with VFIO:

```
09:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] [10de:1b06] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] [1043:85e5]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 128
    Memory at f4000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f5000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [250] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] Secondary PCI Express
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

09:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP102 HDMI Audio Controller [1043:85e5]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 129
    Memory at f5080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

So what could've been causing the crash? From what I can tell it may have something to do with USB devices, but then why would the entire system lock up like that? And how could the problem be fixed?

Thanks!

Edit: from more reading, another thing that may cause the problem might be Ryzen C6 states. What I'm testing currently is to change the BIOS settings of `Power Supply Idle Control` to `typical current`, `Cool n Quiet` to `off`, and `Global C state control` to `disabled`. This seems to work, but only time will tell...

Edit 2: the problem doesn't seem to be with power states. I've however narrowed the problem down to something with either IOMMU or KVM/QEMU.

The freeze only happens when IOMMU is on, and my Windows VM (with a passed-through PCIe device through VFIO) is active. With IOMMU totally off, I've been running for >48 hours now without a crash. But I kind of need the VM to work, so I'll have to investigate further.

Comment: Is it crashing or freezing? Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`? Do you find "stack trace" in /var/log/syslog? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: Updated as per your request! A side note here that at the time of writing, F50a seems to be the latest BIOS version available from Gigabyte.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Overclocking**

If you've overclocked your CPU or RAM, reset it to normal.

**BIOS**

You're already at the latest, F50a.

**Ryzen**

Some Ryzen 7 1800X processors don't work well under Linux. There's a recall.

See https://www.extremetech.com/computing/254750-amd-replaces-ryzen-cpus-users-affected-rare-linux-bug

**Memory**

Assure that memory is installed in equal matched pairs so that the system can take advantage of memory interleaving. Use `sudo lshw -C memory` to confirm configuration. Confirm proper channel A/channel B configuration.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Swap**

Your swap is insanely large. I'd reduce it to 4G and see how that works out.

Comment: So there's no overclock of any kind on the system, and the processor was replaced a year ago - for exactly the problem you referred to. I've edited the original post to include some more memory data. I've also yet to run a memtest, but I'll do that soon.

The other thing I noticed is that if I turn my VM off (VFIO setup with PCIe passthrough for Windows apps/games), the system _seems_ to not crash, although this is only a few hours in...

Comment: @Namo `sudo lshw -C memory` doesn't clearly indicate the proper use of memory channels in its shown output. Refer to the user manual for that motherboard, and look for a section on configuring memory, as it should tell you what two slots to use first, and those should be one matched pair. The second matched pair would go into the remaining slots.

Comment: @Namo Status please...

Comment: From experimentation, it looks like the problem is going to be with either IOMMU, or KVM somewhere. I'm still trying to figure it out.

Memtest was great, everything was installed per documentation. I've narrowed down the crash - it only occurs when IOMMU is on, and I have my VM running with a passed-through PCIe device. With IOMMU disabled, I'm now seeing >48h uptimes with no issues, so I believe the problem would be there somewhere.

Comment: @Namo Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a memory problem or voltage problem.

I've noticed that your RAM memory is from two different vendors with different sizes. It also seems, by the output of the memory configuration that you are alternating between the memories:

Bank1 : Kingston 8GB
Bank2 : Unbranded 16GB
Bank3 : Kingston 8GB
Bank4 : Unbranded 16GB

You should keep memories of the same size and the same brand in adjacent banks.

If the memory swap doesn't do the job, I would check for the power unit. You seem to have a pretty potent machine there (actually it's pretty much the same setup that I have: 48GB RAM, Geforce 1080, but I have an Intel 8770k) so you need a power unit that can handle all that.

If you check the specs page for the [GTX 1080Ti](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1080-ti/specifications) you'll see that only by itself it consumes 250W. If you're using a power unit on the 300W/400W range (considering that you're using a good brand, cheaper brands have nominal values of 600w, 700w but their actual output is much lower) there's a big chance that the Graphics board is destabilizing the voltage of the whole system and should look a for more potent power unit.